# Do I need to add a comma before an "and"?

Tags: grammar

"Tap any of the links below to learn about our company, why we created xxx and how you can use the application."

Wondering if there should be another comma before the last "and"

Comment: See Oxford Comma, Harvard Comma, or Serial Comma ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: It's a question of style rather than grammar. I think the sentence would be clearer with a comma added before *and*. I'm assuming that "why" and "how" are separate options with their own links?

Comment: Classic example: 'He eats shoots and leaves' (OK) vs 'He eats, shoots and leaves' (Ummm) vs 'He eats, shoots, and leaves' (OK but different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Generally you include a comma after every item in a list, and the sentence above would qualify. In that case, the comma would be referred to as an Oxford comma. However, a case can be made that you don't necessarily need a comma before and. It really depends on what style of writing you're using, whether or not you're submitting it for a specific task and whether or not they accept it, and/or if it looks right to you. Honestly it depends on any of those criteria.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, for instance

“George, Sophie, and Joe” does need one but “so he hugged her and, well, you know” doesn’t. If you are having problems figuring it out, read your sentence aloud and see which one fits better (example)
Jack, James, and I   VS   Jack, James and I